# Error when upgrade magento 2.4.3

Tags: setup-upgrade, magento2.4.3

I did upgrade the Magento version from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 when run command upgrade show an error
Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogSampleData for module Magento_CatalogSampleData. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.
[image]

Please help me with your ideas so I can fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I did fix the issue with the command: `php bin/magento sampledata:remove` because I upgrade magento version from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 and did not use sample data so it show error when upgrade and currently did fix. thanks all